# Two SSDs, one ubuntu and one windows. Want to choose option for which to boot at start up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I started off by having Ubuntu 16.04 on my primary SSD and later purchased another one and put Windows 10 on it.  I can choose between the two which one I want to boot if I go into BIOS at startup and set booting priorities.  As you can imagine this is inconvenient, so I want to be able to just go into grub or some other gui which allows me to select which drive I want to boot from.

Sorry if this question has been asked.  I looked under a bunch of similar questions and none of them seemed to run into my issues.

Thanks ahead of time.

EDIT:  When I try to run sudo update-grub in terminal this is my output

http://postimg.org/image/ii4pgwgnj/

EDIT:  When I try to run sudo grub-install /dev/sda first I get this output

http://postimg.org/image/cdi2kpy75/

Comment: Just checking: Were both OSes installed in UEFI mode? They were, apparently, so it should be as simple as disabling fast startup in Windows and shutdown (reboot will revert the changes). Then boot Ubuntu and do *sudo update-grub*. It should now recognize Windows 10 and add it to the boot menu. Now booting the Ubuntu UEFI entry should bring up the Grub menu from which you can dualboot.

Comment: So I thought I installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode.  The BIOS only have UEFI preceding the SSD with Windows on it.  Fast startup in Windows and shutdown were disabled before.  What are my options from here?

Comment: Try update-grub. It show show whether or not Windows 10 is detected.

Comment: I did that earlier but to no avail I'm afraid.  I can get you a screenshot when I get home in 10-15 minutes of the output

Comment: It usually works. You may try *sudo grub-install /dev/sda* and then update-grub again. Otherwise I'm afraid you'll have to dualboot from the UEFI menu only.

Comment: I'm running into an error when I run that line.  Displayed above.

Comment: So you installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode. You should always install in the same mode of the other OS. Dualboot (with Grub) cannot work otherwise.

Comment: So do I have to reinstall Ubuntu to get it to work?  When I install I need to use UEFI?

Comment: Always prefer UEFI mode when available. Any factory installed Windows 8/8.1/10 is UEFI so Ubuntu must be also be installed in UEFI mode for proper dualbooting. If you just installed, I would suggest reinstalling. Otherwise, you can always boot from UEFI.

Comment: Just created Ubuntu Live USB.  Now do you think it's wiser to install on the same SSD or keep it separate?

Comment: Do as you wish.

Comment: Just make sure the GRUB bootloader will be put on the disk which will be the first one in the UEFI boot order. That way, you'll be able to choose the OS you want to boot into, at each startup.